# How is CODE-E a prequel of MISSION-E?

Tags: code-e, mission-e

The code CODE-E series revolves around a girl that has the ability to generate electromagnetic waves. It basically follows the protagonist around in her ordinary life with the annoyance of wrecking almost anything that is electronic. After watching the last episode, I continued with MISSION-E and came across a completely different situation that suggests I have missed quite a portion of story.

How is *CODE-E* a prequel of *MISSION-E*? Should I watch/read something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some amount of time has passed after "CODE-E". The main change in the background story is that they've discovered that there are other people like Chinami, or other *TYPE-E*'s in the world. This discovery (prompted by events from "CODE-E") lead to discrimination and persecution of TYPE-E's. This lead to Chinami, her friends, and some of the people she had confrontations with from CODE-E forming an organization called "OZ" which tries to help other people with the same abilities as Chinami, or other TYPE-E's. And that's where the story starts in MISSION-E.

There is an ongoing manga called "CODE-EX" and a light novel series also called "CODE-E" (which, I believe, was an adaptation of the anime series), but I'm not sure how much they fill in the missing time between the "CODE-E" and "MISSION-E" anime.